# How to get string of selection field?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

i have following selection fields in my module i want to get string value of selection field. suppose user select `'o'` i want to print `O - Original` please provide me any better solution.

```
type = fields.Selection([
                        ('o', 'O - Original'),
                        ('a', 'A - Amended')],
                         string="Is this an Original Invoice or Amended Invoice ?"
```

## i have this solution

```
def get_string_value_of_selection():
    if self.type == 'o':
        value = "O - Original", 
    if self.type == 'a':
        value = "A - Amended"

    print "value = ",value
```

## output

if user select `o`

```
value = O - Original
```

Comment: I just print it out in xml '<t t-if="doc.type" t-esc="[x[1] for x in o._fields['type'].selection if x[0]==o.type][0]"/>'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it can be archive as follow. working in odoo 9, 10 not tried in 8

```
print dict(self._fields['type'].selection).get(self.type)
```

if user select `o`

**output**
O - Original